# VS2010 built COM component vs regasm /codebase on separate machine

Tags: c#, com

What does VS do to make a COM component work when you build the project that regasm /codebase does not?

When I consume the component on the PC where I built it it works fine.  When I try to consume it on a separate PC, the methods are not found.

Is this some GAC type issue?

Thanks

Comment: "Methods are not found" is not a .NET exception message.  Provide a better diagnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in REGASM

REGASM mystuff.dll /codebase /tlb:mystuff.tlb